# How can I interpret $\mathbf y=Z\mathbf x$, where $y_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[x_i\cos(\pi i/n)+x_{n-i}\sin(\pi i/n)\right].$

Tags: matrices

I have a vector $\mathbf x$ with size $n\times 1$, it's multiplied with an $n\times n$ matrix $Z$, the resulted $n\times 1$ vector is $\mathbf y = Z\mathbf x$. I know that each value of $y_i$, where $i = 0,1, 2,\dots,n-1$ is as follows:

$$y_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left [ x_i\cos\left(\frac{\pi i}{n}\right)+x_{n-i}\sin\left(\frac{\pi i}{n}\right)\right].$$

In that case, how can I explain the matrix $Z$? For example can I say that $(j,k)$-th entry of $Z$ be explained as follows:

$$\left(Z\right)_{j,k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathrm{cos}\left ( \frac{\pi i}{n} \right ) + \mathrm{sin}\left ( \frac{\pi i}{n}\right).$$

If not, what is the correct form of $Z$ which can explain that relationship?

Comment: Show your steps of getting to the expression for $(Z)_{j,k}$ and then someone can point out a mistake or confirm that it's correct.

Comment: @sadman-ncc I really don't know how to get the expression of $Z$, for that I was wondering if I can express it as the second equation in the question.

Comment: Your $y_n$is defined in terms of $x_0$, but $x_0$ is not defined. Should that $x_{n-i}$ term instead be $x_{n+1-i}$?

Comment: @dshin I edited it.